# Could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

```
Your bundle is locked to faker (1.6.3), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of faker (1.6.3) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of faker (1.6.3) that hasn't been removed in order to install.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I am getting this error even if i install `1.6.3` or `1.6.5` or `1.6.6`.

`gem list` has `faker (1.6.6, 1.6.3)`

[bundle env](https://gist.github.com/farhansalam/c368dce73e8e05f0037d0fe603e9a0ef)

`gem install faker` works fine, and installs the latest `1.6.6`

I get this error while running rails **server** and **console**.

Comment: can you delete your Gemfile.lock file and run bundle install command.

Comment: tried that, didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it worked!!!

`bundle install --binstubs`

`bundle exec rails c`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added source in your Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'faker', '~> 1.6.3'
```

Then run

```
bundle update faker
```

This should solve your issue

Comment: The source was there, as there were all other gems present, i updated the faker as I said and tried multiple different versions